# O AlarmManager não cancela o alarme agendado

Tags: java, android, android-alarmmanager

Eu tenho o seguinte código no `MyReceiver`:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

        context.startService(new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class));
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context, long mills){

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReceiverNotification.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2310, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (mills + 60000), 120000, pi);
    }

    public void setAlarmCancel(Context context){

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2310, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.cancel(sender);

        Log.v(TAG, "Alarme cancelado!");

    }
```

E tenho este para as notificações:

```
public class ReceiverNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        context.startService(new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));
    }
}
```

Quando eu agendo para uma determinada hora, chamar o método `setAlarmCancel()`, tenho o retorno do LOG mas o alarme continua. Agradecia uma ajuda ...

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Comment: @rrnan, feito ;)

Answer (score 1):

Alterei a linha `Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);` para `Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReceiverNotification.class);`

```
public void setAlarmCancel(Context context){

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReceiverNotification.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2310, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.cancel(sender);

        Log.v(TAG, "Alarme cancelado!");

    }
```